# Decode the cipher encoded string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, cryptography

I have encoded a string using this method in Python. I want to decode the encoded string using Javascript.

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import XOR
def encrypt(key, plaintext):
    cipher = XOR.new(key)
    return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(plaintext))
```

Comment: What is `XOR`? what library are you using?

Comment: @rdas: It's likely [pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/).

Comment: You just reverse the process. First, base64 decode. Then xor the result with the key.

Answer (score 2):

I got a better solution to encrypt in Python and decrypt in Javascript.

Python Encoding Part:

```
 import base64
 from Crypto import Random
 from Crypto.Cipher import AES
 import json

 def encrypt_val(clear_text):
    master_key = '0123456789101112' 
    encoder = PKCS7Encoder()
    raw = encoder.encode(clear_text)
    iv = Random.new().read( 16 )
    cipher = AES.new( master_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv, segment_size=128 )
    return base64.b64encode( iv + cipher.encrypt( raw ) ) 

 print(encrypt_val(json.dumps({"name":"Tahir"})))
```

Javascript Decoding Part:

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js')
const atob = require('atob')

function decryptMsg (data) {
    master_key = '0123456789101112';

    // Decode the base64 data so we can separate iv and crypt text.
    var rawData = atob(data);
    // Split by 16 because my IV size
    var iv = rawData.substring(0, 16);
    var crypttext = rawData.substring(16);

    //Parsers
    crypttext = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(crypttext);
    iv = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(iv); 
    key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(master_key);

    // Decrypt
    var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      { ciphertext:  crypttext},
      key,
      {iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7}
    );

    // Can be Utf8 too
    output_plaintext = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.stringify(plaintextArray);
    console.log("plain text : " + output_plaintext);
}
encoded_message = "XF8T/miPPVk9B7GfNUshRqJf6//sJnWey+TqoXj70Tp0vJhjw22uDLOLh7es4BOp"
decryptMsg(encoded_message)
```